# Use FineUploader to upload multiple files with index

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, fine-uploader

I am using [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) plugin for my image upload function, and I'm having trouble finding a way to track the index of the file when `multiple` option is enabled.

What I am doing on the server side upon handling the image upload is, I would query the existing images from database, get the count, and save the link of the newly uploaded image with index equals to `existing_count+1` to the database.

This should allow me to have a record of all uploaded images, with their upload order as index.

However, with `multiple` option enabled, when the uploader is accessing my server endpoint for the subsequent files, the database query doesn't seem to update from the last image save.

Is this a race condition? Is there a way to pass the file index to server?

Here are my code:

server side (Laravel)

```
public function save_listing_picture() {
     if (Input::hasFile('listing')) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $id = $user->id;
        $existing_count = Image::where('user_id', $id)->count(); //this doesn't update on a multiple upload request

        $file = Input::file('listing');
        $imagePath = '/images/'+$id+'/image_'+$existing_count+1+'.jpg';
        $img = Image::make($file)->encode('jpg', 75);
        $img->save($imagePath);

        $imgRecord = new Image();
        $imgRecord->link = $imagePath;
        $imgRecord->save();
    }
}
```

front end (JS):

```
var listingUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById("image-uploader"),
        template: 'qq-template',
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/account/save-image',
            params: {'_token': csrf_token},
            inputName: 'listing'
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: '/img/fine-uploader/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: '/img/fine-uploader/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        image: {
            minHeight: 300,
            minWidth: 300
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            itemLimit: 3
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of using the index, which is not unique across upload sets and users, why not instead reference files by the UUID sent with the upload request by Fine Uploader?

Comment: @RayNicholus thanks. I use sequence thinking that it's easier to retrieve the image URL on the frontend. I guess at this point, a UUID is a better approach.

Comment: Each upload request includes a `qquuid` parameter with this UUID. Do you need any further help?

Comment: @RayNicholus is there a way to retrieve the `qquuid` on a complete callback? just trying to refresh the image on the frontend when upload completes.

Comment: Given the ID of a file, which is provided to your `onComplete` callback handler, you can retrieve the UUID using [`getUuid(id)`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid).

Comment: @RayNicholus, thanks it works. Please add an answer :)

Comment: I can do that, or you can write the code that solves the exact problem for you, given my advice. I'd be happy to upvote your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `UUID` to track each of the file uploaded, to avoid duplication and faulty override (thanks to @RayNicholus for the suggestion).

Here is my solution:

server side

```
public function save_listing_picture(Request $request) {
    if (Input::hasFile('listing')) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $id = $user->id;

        $file = Input::file('listing');

        $fileId = $request->get('qquuid');
        $destination_path = 'images/' . $id . '/';
        if (!is_dir($destination_path)) {
            mkdir($destination_path, 0777, true);
        }
        $full_path = $destination_path . $fileId . ".jpg";
        $img = Image::make($file)->encode('jpg', 75);
        $img->save(public_path() . '/' . $full_path);

        $imgRecord = new Image();
        $imgRecord->link = $full_path;
        $imgRecord->save();


        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'Input not found']);
}
```

front end:

```
var userId = {{Auth::user()->id}}; //laravel blade
var listingUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("image-uploader"),
    template: 'qq-template',
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: '/account/save-image',
        params: {'_token': csrf_token},
        inputName: 'listing'
    },
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: '/img/fine-uploader/waiting-generic.png',
            notAvailablePath: '/img/fine-uploader/not_available-generic.png'
        }
    },
    image: {
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 300
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        itemLimit: 3
    },
    callbacks: {
            onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
                if (succeeded.length > 0) {
                    succeeded.forEach(function(fileId, index) {
                    var imageId = "image" + index;
                    document.getElementById(imageId).src='images/' + userId + '/' + listingUploader.getUuid(fileId)+".jpg";
                    });
                }
            }
        }
});
```